# can I store similar objects in a C# array list

Tags: c#, list, class

I'm not very good at this C# stuff yet...

I am trying to create a list of simple objects to later serialize to JSON.  Problem is, sometimes, I need the object to be of one type, and sometimes, of another.  The difference in the two objects is minimal.

Here are the two similar classes (you'll get the idea):

```
class DataCell 
{
  string cellName {get; set;}
  string cellValue {get; set;}
}

class LinkCell
{
  string cellName {get; set;}
  linkObject cellValue = new linkObject("linkString", "linkHREF", "linkOnClick");
  //linkObject is a simple class with only 3 strings as well
}
```

My question is whether there is a way to create a base class of say type "TableCell" that both of these classes could then inherit from and then be able to add either to my list? Or is there a better way to handle this (I'm sure there is, just not one that I've stumbled across yet!)

Comment: object cellValue {get; set;} ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could if they are inherited from the same base class:

```
class CellBase 
{
  string Name {get; set;}
  string Value {get; set;}
}

class DataCell : CellBase 
{
  //Data specific properties
}

class LinkCell : CellBase
{
  linkObject cellValue = new linkObject("linkString", "linkHREF", "linkOnClick");
  //linkObject is a simple class with only 3 strings as well
}

//Now create your list with

List<CellBase> cells
```

or if your collection is generic, i.e.

```
List<object> cells
```

Comment: What is Cell in List<Cell>? Do you mean CellBase?

Comment: I think you mean `List<CellBase>`

Comment: Yep thanks, I did a last minute rename of the base class and forgot to fix the last line